# pgeom and ppois returning incorrect values when trying to find values greater or less than q

Tags: r, distribution

I am a beginner in R and stats, so I apologize if this question has an easy answer that I am just not seeing.

I am looking to solve some problems that want a cumulative answer < or > than *q*. Here is an example:

An actress has a probability of getting offered a job after a try-out of 0.08. She plans to keep trying out for new jobs until she gets offered one. Assume outcomes of try-outs are independent.
Find the probability she will need to attend more than 4 try-outs.

I thought this would be straightforward use of `pgeom`:

`pgeom(q = 4, prob = 0.08, lower.tail = FALSE)` which returns 0.6590815

This is not the correct answer to the problem. I tried `1 - pgeom(q = 4, prob = 0.08)`, which obviously still gave the same answer. I tried setting `q = 5` to see if maybe R was including 4 when it should be excluded. Still wrong. (The correct answer to the problem is 0.7164.)

Running into the same issue with `ppois`. Can anyone explain what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Have you considered using the negative-binomial distribution?

Comment: @IRTFM how is this a negative binomial?

Comment: Number of tries until success?

Comment: `pgeom` is 0-based, meaning it is counting the number of *failed* try-outs. If you are starting with total try-outs, you have to subtract the one successful try-out to get the number of failed try-outs: `pgeom(4 - 1, 0.08, FALSE)`.

Comment: The negative binomial also works, as the geometric distribution is a special case of the negative binomial where the size parameter (the target number of successes) equals 1: `pnbinom(4 - 1, 1, 0.08, lower.tail = FALSE)`.

Comment: @jblood94 your explanation is not correct. in the question, they write "probability for more than 4 tryouts". This means at least 5 tryouts. Then if you do 5-1 to get the number of failed try outs = 4. Read my answer to see why you have to write `pgeom(3, .08, F)` to get the correct result.

Comment: You correctly point out that `lower.tail = FALSE` excludes the values less than *and equal to* the value given for the `q` parameter (in this case 3), but this is the way all the discrete probability distributions work in R's `stats` package (`pbinom`, `ppois`, `pnbinom`, `rgeom`, etc.). It may not be intuitive for you, but it is at least consistent. There are two possible sources of the OP's confusion: 1) the OP does not realize `pgeom` is 0-based (which requires subtracting 1 from the *total* number of try-outs as I explained, or 2) the OP does not realize `lower.tail` is exclusive. (cont.)

Comment: My explanation is quite correct. To illustrate, `dgeom(0, 0.08)` returns `0.08`, which should be read, "the probability of experiencing 0 *failed* try-outs is `0.08`". Consider instead the question, "what is the probability the actress has to attend more than 1 try-out *total*?". We cannot ask `pgeom` that question directly. We can only ask the probability that the actress experiences a certain number of *failed* try-outs, which would be 1 total - 1 successful = 0 failed, hence `pgeom(1 - 1, 0.08, lower.tail = FALSE)`.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:**
`lower.tail = F` behaves unintuitively - unlike the default, `lower.tail = T`, it does not include the given value in the interval. See below for explanation.

---

R help for `?pgeom` says:

> x, q
> vector of quantiles **representing the number of failures [...] before success** occurs.

For example, success on 5th tryout = 4 failures.

Remember that `dgeom()` is giving the probability for a single, exact number of failures before first success. We want the sum of `dgeom()` across all possible numbers of failures greater or equal to 4.

```r
dgeom(4:1000000, .08) |> sum()
#> 0.716393
```

So, this is the correct result. But how to achieve it with `pgeom()`?

```r
1 - pgeom(3, .08)
#> 0.716393
```

It makes sense from this perspective: The 4 is included in the compliment we are looking for, therefore we should not include in the other part.

This is also represented in the behaviour of `lower.tail = FALSE` and `lower.tail = TRUE`. Our intuition tells us, both should behave the same and include the given value in the interval...

Like you, I would expect

```r
pgeom(4, .08, lower.tail = F)
#> 0.6590815
```

to give cumulative probabilities from 4 onwards. Instead, it is giving the probability for 5 or more failures before the first success:

```r
dgeom(5:1000000, .08) |> sum()
#> 0.6590815
```

To understand this behaviour of the `lower.tail` argument, see what help says about it:

[image: help]

The equivalence relation is only included for `TRUE`, the default.
When `FALSE`, the direction changes like expected, but now the equivalence relation is gone. Sad for intuition, great for maths: `lower.tail = T` and `lower.tail = F` are counterparts that have to add up to 1. So the given value can only be included in one of them, otherwise the following would not add up to 1:

```r
pgeom(4, .08, lower.tail = T) + pgeom(4, .08, lower.tail = F)
#> 1
```

Luckily, developers chose that the default behaviour is to include the given value in the interval. That means we can use this function intuitively, and just resort to `1 - pgeom()` to be explicit about wanting the compliment, where the value is obviously not included.

Comment: I dont know what you are saying. The code `1 - pgeom(3, 0.08)` is exactly same as `pgeom(3, 0.08, FALSE)`.

Comment: yes, it is, and that is good. My point is: when I just type `pgeom(3, .08, FALSE)` I would expect that it gives *p* for the interval with 3 included, just like `pgeom(3, .08)` includes 3 in the interval. However, this is just my personal expectation. But op also committed the same mistake, so maybe I am not alone.